# Why is One Class SVM predicting that half my dataset consists of outliers?

Tags: svm, scikit-learn, outliers, isolation-forest, localoutlierfactor

I am currently working on a dataset with 14 continuous features, a categorical target over five classes, and 90,000 samples. My current goal is to explore outliers in the dataset, and to that end I have been experimenting with Scikit-Learn's implementations of Isolation Forest, Local Outlier Factor, and One Class SVM. Here is a summary of the number of outliers detected and the two most-outlying classes for each model:

Local Outlier Factor identifies 830 outliers (44% in class 3 and 29% in class 0)

Isolation Forest identifies 16,430 outliers (52% in class 3 and 25% in class 2)

One Class SVM identifies 45,000 outliers (34% in class 3 and 31% in class 0)

I might also add that Local Outlier Factor and One Class SVM's third most-outlying class is also class 2. But to the point, I only have a rudimentary understanding of each of these algorithms and overall limited experience in outlier detection, so I am having a hard time interpreting these results. Moreover, it seems highly odd that the one class SVM would decide that *exactly* half my dataset is outlying, and I would like to understand why class 3 consistently makes up the largest proportion of the set of outliers.

If anyone could point me towards some analytic techniques or explanations which might help me better analyze these results, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Are these the results on your training set or testing/validation set?

Comment: @jonnor these are the results on all my data, I don't have a labeled set of outliers to use.

Comment: You should still do train/val/test splitting, to have test results on indepdentent samples from those used during fitting and hyperparameter optimization.

Comment: What do you mean by 'targets' - that sounds like you have a label/ground truth?

Comment: Are you doing one outlier detection model per 'target'? Or a joint model?

Comment: I have a ground truth for each sample indicating which class it belongs to, and in regards to this question I am trying to train an outlier model over all the classes.

Comment: Ok. How are you extracting the anomaly score, and setting the threshold for what is anomaly and not?

Comment: What is the number of outliers that you expect in this dataset?

Answer (score 2):

- All of those methods have hyperparameters, are you sure you use reasonable values for the hyperparameters? Scikit-learn has [nice article](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) on them.
- Not much can be said without access to your data and actual results. What you could do, is to just produce a lot of all kind of plots and summary statistics for all of the parameters, grouped by the classification results to try to understand what is going on. It is useful to look at the raw predictions as well, you can just take something like ten least anomalous and ten most anomalous samples (as classified by the algorithm) and compare them, how do they differ?
- You can check the [Interpretable Machine Learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/) book by Christoph Molnar that is freely available online for more ideas and description of most advanced methods for interpreting the results.